# Prove the diagonalizing matrix $P$ of a hermitian matrix $A$ is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a hermitian matrix ($A=A^{\dagger}$) with $n$ eigenvectors $\{\vec{v}_k\}_{k=1}^{n}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times1}$ and corresponding eigenvalues $\{\lambda_k\}_{k=1}^n$. It is given that $\lambda_j\neq\lambda_k$ for all $j,k\in[1,n]_{\mathbb{N}},j\neq k$, and that:

$$||\vec{v}_k||=1\quad \forall k\in[1,n]_{\mathbb{N}}$$

Let $P\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a square matrix, such that its columns are the eigenvectors of $A$:

$$P=\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    | & | & \cdots & | \\
    \vec{v}_1 & \vec{v}_2 & \cdots & \vec{v}_n \\
    | & | & \cdots & | \\
    \end{matrix}
\right)$$

Prove that $P$ is **unitary**, meaning $P^{-1}=P^\dagger$.

---

I'm sure that there is more than one proof somewhere in the forum. I didn't bother to search because I don't want to know how to prove the statement, I just need help completing my proof (or altering what has be to changed).

**Proof:** First, define a diagonal matrix $D\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that:

$$D=\text{diag}\{\lambda_k\}_{k=1}^n$$

It is clear that $P^{-1}$ exists. Let $\{\vec{u}_k\}_{k=1}^n\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times n}$ be the row vectors that build $P^{-1}$, such that:

$$P^{-1}=\left(
    \begin{matrix}
    - & \vec{u}_1 & - \\
    - & \vec{u}_2 & - \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    - & \vec{u}_n & - \\
    \end{matrix}
\right)$$

Then, we can see that:

$$A_{jk}=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\sum_{l=1}^{n}P_{jm}D_{ml}P^{-1}_{lk}=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\sum_{l=1}^{n}(\vec{v}_m)_j\delta_{ml}\lambda_{m}(\vec{u}_l)_k=\sum_{m=1}^{n}(\vec{v}_m)_j\lambda_{m}(\vec{u}_m)_k$$

Since $A$ is hermitian, its eigenvalues are real, and $A_{jk}=A^\star_{kj}$ for all $j,k\in[1,n]_\mathbb{N}$. We can see that:

$$A^\star_{kj}=\sum_{m=1}^{n}(\vec{u}^\star_m)_j\lambda_{m}(\vec{v}^\star_m)_k$$

Therefore:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{n}(\vec{u}^\star_m)_j\lambda_{m}(\vec{v}^\star_m)_k=\sum_{m=1}^{n}(\vec{v}_m)_j\lambda_{m}(\vec{u}_m)_k$$

In order to prove $P$ is unitary, we need to show that $\vec{v}_m=(\vec{u}^T_m)^\star$ for all $m\in[1,n]_\mathbb{N}$. We can see clearly that if this equality is true, then $A_{jk}=A^\star_{kj}$ as we expect. But I need the opposite direction - I need to prove that $\vec{v}_m=(\vec{u}^T_m)^\star$ just using the equation above. Not sure how to do that. Also, I haven't used the fact that the eigenvectors are normalized. I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: I feel like you're slightly overcomplicating things. Remember a matrix is unitary iff its' rows (and columns) are orthonormal. What do you know about eigenvectors of a hermitian matrix that correspond to 2 *different* eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

If $ \lambda_j \ne \lambda_k$, then $\vec{v}_j$ and $\vec{v}_k$ are othonormal, thus

$\vec{v}_1,...,\vec{v}_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $ \mathbb C^n.$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Well yes, I guess this is a much easier approach. I was just wondering how to prove it otherwise